# How to grab a web page content, just as the importxml formula would do with Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Basically, I'm building a scraper to get the contents of a web page, so that then I can count a certain keyword occurrence and get that keyword density from the page.
I can already count the number of occurrences, the issue I'm having is that `UrlFetchApp.fetch` pulls the source code I ended up counting not only the words on what would be the frontend of the page but also whatever is on the source code.

for that, I wanted to filter the page so that I only grab the actual content of the page.

I would love to get the content just as `=importxml("[page]","//div[@id='main']")` does in google sheets but I have no idea on how to apply that logic on code, I'm using google scripts so, using `querySelector`, or `getElementsByTag` is not an option, unfortunately.

the reason I'm trying to do this in code and not by using the google sheets formula is that this would be applied to a big number of pages.

````
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options) 
      var html = response.getContentText();

var body = html.substring(html.lastIndexOf("<body") + 1, html.lastIndexOf("</body>"));  //removed everything from above the <body> tag
      
   
var lowerBody = body.toString().toLowerCase()  // changing the contents to lower case so is not case sensitive.

var kw = kw.toString().toLowerCase()  // same as above but for the keyword

 var filter = ['<p>','li','span','h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6'] //what I want to get from the page

   
        var newBody = new Array;     
      var filter = ['p','li','span','h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6']
      
      
    for(var i = 0; i< filter.length; i++){
        
      if(filter[i] == 'p'){
        if(lowerBody.match(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g).length != 0){
          newBody[i] = lowerBody.match(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g).map(function(val){
            return val.replace(/<\/?p>/g,'');
          });       
        }
  
      }
      else if(filter[i] == 'li'){
        if(lowerBody.match(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g).length != 0){
          newBody[i] = lowerBody.match(/<li>(.*?)<\/li>/g).map(function(val){
            return val.replace(/<\/?li>/g,'');
          });
        }
  
      }
      else if(filter[i] == 'span'){
        if(lowerBody.match(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g).length != 0){
          newBody[i] = lowerBody.match(/<span>(.*?)<\/span>/g).map(function(val){
            return val.replace(/<\/?span>/g,'');
          });
        }
      }
      else if(filter[i] == 'h1'){
        if(lowerBody.match(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g).length != 0){
          
          newBody[i] = lowerBody.match(/<h1(.*?)<\/h1>/g).map(function(val){
            return val.replace(/<\/?h1/g,'');
          });
        }
      }
      else if(filter[i] == 'h2'){
        if(lowerBody.match(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g).length != 0){
          
          newBody[i] = lowerBody.match(/<h2(.*?)<\/h2>/g).map(function(val){
            return val.replace(/<\/?h2/g,'');
          });
        }
      }
      else if(filter[i] == 'h3'){
        if(lowerBody.match(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g).length != 0){
          newBody[i] = lowerBody.match(/<h3(.*?)<\/h3>/g).map(function(val){
            return val.replace(/<\/?h3/g,'');
          });
        }
      }
      else if(filter[i] == 'h4'){
        if(lowerBody.match(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g).length != 0){
          newBody[i] = lowerBody.match(/<h4(.*?)<\/h4>/g).map(function(val){
            return val.replace(/<\/?h4/g,'');
          });
        }
      }
        else{
        
        }
      }```

I know my code is bad so I'm willing to scrape all this if there's a better way of accomplishing this.
Thanks in advance.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a **TEMPORARY** sheet, use `setFormula('=IMPORTXML("URL","XPATH")`, retrieve the data and delete the sheet once the operation is finished?

**Example:**

```
function getData() {
    var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var newSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Temporary");
    //check if existing, delete if yes
    if (newSheet != null) {
      activeSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(newSheet);
    }
    //create new sheet with name Temporary
    newSheet = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
    newSheet.setName("Temporary");
    //use method:setFormula and use IMPORTXML
    newSheet.getRange("A1").setFormula('=IMPORTXML("http://www.google.com", "//a/@href")');

    //retrieve and print data
    Logger.log(newSheet.getDataRange().getValues());
    //delete Temporary sheet
    activeSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(newSheet);
}
```

Output:

[image]

Reference:

[method:setFormula](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula)

Comment: Thanks for replying! aa this looks like a good way of doing it, it might be kinda slow for what I'm working on, I'll give it a try, looks like a great way of tackling this issue.
Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

This will get just the body:

```
function simpleScraper(url) {
  let html=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  html=html.slice(html.indexOf('<body>')+6,html.indexOf('</body>'));
  html='<textarea rows="12" cols="30">' + html + '</textarea>';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), "HTML");
}
```

This might help to get the script out:

```
function simpleScraper(url='http://jimesteban.com') {
  let s=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const p1='<textarea rows="12" cols="30">';
  const p2='</textarea>';
  let body=s.slice(s.indexOf('<body>')+6,s.indexOf('</body>'));
  let html;
  if(body.indexOf('<script')==-1) {
    html=body;
  }else{
    let s1=body.slice(0,body.indexOf('<script'));
    let s2=body.slice(body.indexOf('</script>')+8);
    html=s1 + s2;
  }
  if(html.indexOf('<style')!=-1) {
    let a1=html.slice(0,html.indexOf('<style'));
    let a2=html.slice(html.indexOf('</style>')+8);
    html=a1 + a2;
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(p1+html+p2).setWidth(800).setHeight('600'), "HTML");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying~
I gave this a try and is somewhat similar to what I have right now, and unfortunately is does not work for this case.
Thanks for taking your time on this.